# Methods with parameters

Tags: java, variables, methods, parameters

Is there a difference between declaring a variable in method parameters and declaring a variable inside a method? Both print out the same variable but i suppose there is a difference.

Comment: Could you add some code examples to explain what you mean? I think there's a very significant difference between the two but I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: A parameter holds a value that can be passed into the method when you call the function. A variable declared inside the method doesn't.

Comment: The Eclipse tag should be removed, this is just a Java question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by decalring variable as method parameter you can pass variables into method

```
public void printIt(String text){
   System.out.println(text);
}
```

but if you declare variable inside method like this:

```
public void printIt(){
   String name;
   //you can't pass 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to what I think you are, then there is a big difference between the two. Take this for example:

```
public void printText() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

This prints out the text `Hello World`. Now look at this method:

```
printText("Hello World");
public void printText(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

The latter of these two examples offers much more flexibility because you can call the method with any parameter you like, whereas the former will only print `Hello World`, every time. Of course, depending on what you want the method to do, one form might be more appropriate than the other, but method arguments allow reusability.

Answer (score 0):

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> **Local Variables** Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a
>   method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The
>   syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field
>   (for example, `int count = 0;`). There is no special keyword designating
>   a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the
>   location in which the variable is declared — which is between the
>   opening and closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are
>   only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not
>   accessible from the rest of the class.
>
> **Parameters** ... Recall that the signature for the main method is public
>   static void `main(String[] args)`. Here, the args variable is the
>   parameter to this method. The important thing to remember is that
>   parameters are always classified as `"variables"` not `"fields"`.

Answer (score 0):

And also by defining parameters within methods in Java (I guess the same applies for C++ too), which causes to the **Methods Overloading**.

Please look at the examples provided bellow:

```
 public void createPerson(int ID, String name) {
      // do something here
  }

  public void createPerson(double height, String name) {
      // do something here
  }

  public void createPerson(double height, String name, boolean testIt) {
      // do something here
  }
```

So what it helps to do is basically to change the **method signature** of the method, which leads the developer to implement different different method bodies within the 3 methods but with the same name but with different method signatures.

Read further about methods in the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) from Oracle Java.

Hope this is helpful to your question.